# use two different configs in one postfix, is it possible?

Tags: postfix, smtpd

I'm wondering if is it possible to specify another `main.cf` for the configuration of smptd service in another port paired with normal config in standard port.

I know that is it possible to override `main.cf` settings in `master.cf` using the `-o <key>=<value>` parameter for smtpd service definitions but I'm asking for a way to directly tell to smtpd to read another main configuration file.

Can it be done?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? You could always make a link to a file (`ln`). Would that suffice?

Comment: No, that not suffice. I'm trying to keep old config in port 25 and new config in 2525

Answer (score 1):

A quick look through the [source code](http://www.postfix.org/download.html) leads me to believe that this isn't possible with the native distro package.

The filename `main.cf` is hard-coded in several places.

You could try modifying the source before compiling it (`sed -ri 's/main.cf/mymain.cf/'`) but I doubt that'll work without a hitch.

**TL;DR:** Make a file link (`ln`).

Comment: No, It is not just keep the config in another file. I want different configs on different ports, but thanks for the code review :). It is a good way to understand what can be done

Answer (score 0):

http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html describes how to use [postmulti(1)](http://www.postfix.org/postmulti.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Postfix uses two hard-coded filename for its config **main.cf** and **master.cf** (See @Belmin answer).

If your purpose is running postfix via cli with specific file configuration (like `./someprograms -c myconfigfile.cf`), you can use **-C** parameter. Instead a file name, you can specify  a directory where main.cf and master.cf reside. So if you have **main.cf** and **master.cf** inside a directory `/etc/anotherpostfixconf/`, then you can start posfix by

```
postfix -C /etc/anotherpostfixconf/
```

See [Postfix manual - postfix(1)](http://www.postfix.org/postfix.1.html) for further explanation.